# Get string from a class to web api

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a string in one class, I would like to get the string in my web api for the get request and add the value to my query. This is my code to get data from my Mysql database:

**Web api**

```
  // GET: api/Blog
    [HttpGet]
    public List<BlogViews>  Get()
    {

            string sqlstring = "server=; port= ; user id =;Password=;Database=;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlstring);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM test.blogtable where `Category` =" +;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader MSQLRD = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<BlogViews> GetBlogList = new List<BlogViews>();

            if (MSQLRD.HasRows)
            {

              while (MSQLRD.Read())
              {
                BlogViews BV = new BlogViews();
                BV.id = (MSQLRD["id"].ToString());
                BV.DisplayTopic = (MSQLRD["Topic"].ToString());
                BV.DisplayMain = (MSQLRD["Summary"].ToString());
                GetBlogList.Add(BV);
              }
            }
            conn.Close();
        return GetBlogList;
    }
```

**My Class**

```
    public class ItemsClass
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Entry IdEntry = new Entry{};
        public Button DoneButton = new Button{};

        public ItemsClass()
        {
             Content = new StackLayout
             {
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("35ddcf"),
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 10),
            Children = { IdEntry,DoneButton }

              };
        }

    private void DoneButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       IdEntry.Text = id;

       BlogContentsRestClient<BlogContentItemClass> restClient = new 
       BlogContentsRestClient<BlogContentItemClass>();
       await restClient.GetAsync();
    }

    }
```

**HttpRequest Class**

```
 public class BlogContentsRestClient<T>
{
    private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:57645/api/BlogContents/";


    public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
    {

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

        var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

        return taskModels;
    }
```

}

**Question**

In my Web api Query`string Query = "SELECT * FROM test.blogtable where 'Category' =" +;`. I would like to add the value of `string id` in `ItemsClass`, so that I can get data from my Mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get what you mean by add the value of a class to your API method. `ItemsClass` is an object definition and not an instance of it. However you can provide your API method a `parameter` so that you have:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<BlogViews> Get(string id)
```

You can now call your API passing that parameter: `/api/?id={insert here the id}`

Alternatively you can call it in your request's body.

```
[HttpGet]
public List<BlogViews> Get([FromQuery, BindRequired] string id)
```

**EDIT**:

Check if this solution fits:

**1**) Use the method I posted before replacing this:

```
public List<BlogViews> Get()
```

with this:

```
public List<BlogViews> Get(string id)
```

**2**) Edit the `GetAsync()` method as follow:

```
// Added string id as parameter
public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync(string id)
{
    // webUrl now become the same as WebServiceUrl but with parameter added
    string webUrl = "http://localhost:57645/api/BlogContents/?id=" + id; 
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(webUrl);
    var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

    return taskModels;
}
```

**3**) Edit the `DoneButton_Clicked` this way:

```
private void DoneButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IdEntry.Text = id;

    BlogContentsRestClient<BlogContentItemClass> restClient = new 
    BlogContentsRestClient<BlogContentItemClass>();
    await restClient.GetAsync(id); // Here you call the Get API with the id as parameter
}
```

**4**) Finally you can edit the query inside your `Get(string id)` method adding the id to the end:

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM test.blogtable where `Category` =" + id;
```

Comment: i would like to get the value of the `string id`  from the class `ItemsClass` in my Web Api,  not just any string with the name id, When i type in the text in `IdEntry` and click `DoneButton` the string id would be equal to the text in `IdEntry` hence i woul like to get that value in my web api get request .

Comment: Please provide the code where you process the `DoneButton`.

Comment: i dont understand, its already there, the `DoneBotton_clicked` event in `ItemsClass`.

Comment: Let me understand a bit better what you're asking. Once you click the `DoneButton` you want to call your `Get()` API method and use that id in the query you mentioned, am I right?

Comment: Yes, i will make the request also,why should i provide the request code too?

Comment: I didn't ask for the request code, I cannot understand how you want to link the `ItemClass` to the `Get()` method without passing it any parameters at all.

Comment: i edited the question and added the request, see if that helps to understand how my request will be made.

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer. Using parameter is the only thing I can think of to get to a solution.

Comment: Thanks ,It was perfect.Thanks for your patience.